# Is it possible to make a dynamic downcast?

Tags: c#, downcast

How to downcast with strongly runtime known type ?

```
public class A {}

public class B : A { public int i; }

public class C
{
    B b = new B();
    A a = b;               // here upcast, and "a" still keeps link to "b"
    ((B)a).i;              // no problem it works

    Type t = b.GetType();  // BUT how to downcast with strongly runtime known type ?
    ((t)a).i;              // like here
}
```

Comment: There’s several casting syntaxes out there: var a = (A)b;   var a = (b as A);

Comment: Since the compiler doesn't know what `t` is, it doesn't know whether the member `i` exists or not. If you are fine without compile time checking of members, then you can try `dynamic`...

Comment: Type Casting using `((t)a)` requires that `t` is known at compile time, before the program runs. In this code `t` clearly isn't known at compile time because it is a variable that gets its value at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with any runtime conversion, such as using `Convert.ChangeType`, you will only get back `object` which means you wont be able to do anything useful (such as set a property) without using reflection.

One possibility for "I dont know the type, but I'm confident I can set a given property" is the use of `dynamic`:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b; 
dynamic x = a;
x.i = 100;
Console.WriteLine(b.i); /// writes 100.
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/WJDQQ44845

Note this shows an appropriate error if you try to call a property/method which does not exists:

```
x.nosuchproperty =  100;
```

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Rextester.B' does not contain a definition for 'nosuchproperty'

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I have Net 3.5 only ?
Net 3.5 have not "dynamic ".